# Login page: Client to server request being sent twice? Node.js, AngularJS, express framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web, webstorm

This is the client-side AngularJS code snippet:

```
<form name="login" ng-submit="login()">
    <div class="login" ng-app="loginPage" ng-controller="loginController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="uname" name="userid"><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="pword" name="pswrd"><br>
        <!--<input type="button" ng-click="login();" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>-->
        <button ng-click="login();">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
    var app = angular.module('loginPage', []);
    app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http, $window) {
        console.log("inside controller");
        $scope.login = function() {
            console.log("inside the login function");
            console.log($scope.uname);

            var login_http = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/login',
                params: { username: $scope.uname, password: $scope.pword }
            }).then(
                    function (response) {
                        $window.alert('successfull!!');
                        //alert('successfull ...');
                    }, function (response) {
                        $window.alert('wrong username/password');
                        //alert('wrong username/password ... ');
                    }
            )
        }
```

This is the server-side node.js code:

```
connection.connect();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'login.html'));
});
router.post('/login', function(req,res)
{

  console.log("Username:"+req.query.username);
  console.log("Password:"+req.query.password);

  var user = req.query.username;
  var pass = req.query.password

  connection.query("select * from user where login_name = ?", user, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err){
        if(user==rows[0].login_name && pass==rows[0].pass){
             console.log("success");
             res.sendStatus(200);
            //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'team_list.html'));
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
```

I am working in WebStorm and I run app.js which says it's listening to localhost:8000. I go to localhost:8000 on my browser. Type in test for username and test for password (I already have this in my sql database). It says "success!"

Meanwhile, my console (while I am running app.js) in webstorm, says this:

sometimes says this:

```
Server listening on port 8000
GET / 200 10.853 ms - 5260
Username:test
Password:test
success
POST /login?password=test&username=test 200 12.559 ms - 2
GET /?userid=test&pswrd=test 200 10.027 ms - 5260
```

and sometimes says this:

```
Server listening on port 8000
GET / 304 16.586 ms - -
Username:test
Password:test
success
POST /login?password=test&username=test 200 12.778 ms - 2
GET /?userid=test&pswrd=test 304 9.742 ms - -
```

This makes me think that the request is being sent twice. Ideally I would want to console to only do the POST and not the GET. How do I fix this. I'm pretty sure the error is in the angularJS code and I'm doing something wrong with the ng-submit.

@MichaelNakayama I tried changing the form to a div:

```
<div class="login" ng-app="loginPage" ng-controller="loginController">
     <!--name="login" ng-submit="login()"-->

        <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="uname" name="userid"><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="pword" name="pswrd"><br>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="login"/>
        <!--button ng-click="login();">Login</button-->
</div>
```

and then got this in the console:

```
Server listening on port 8000
GET / 304 9.312 ms - -
Username:test
Password:test
C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:
78
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'login_name' of undefined
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\routes\index.js:30
:25)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\node_modules\my
sql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:85:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\nod
e_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:144:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\node_modules\mysql
\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:128:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\node_modules
\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\node_modules\mysql\li
b\protocol\Parser.js:74:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\node_modules\mysql\
lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dagarw\WebstormProjects\GP-01_DEV\node_modules\my
sql\lib\Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

Comment: If you open the network tab in the developer console on your browser, does it show two xhr requests being sent out? Additionally, if you are using a session manager, it might be the case that the user is already logged in which could cause a not modified response.

Comment: I am just getting one. @MichaelNakayama

Comment: Then you aren't sending two requests. Getting two different responses simply means that your session is different on the server when you are making those requests.

Comment: Oh I see, basically, you have an issue where your form is submitting and you're click handler is firing off a request at the same time. A solution would be to change the form to a div. Or prevent the form from submitting a request. I can't quite remember off the top of my head how.

Comment: @MichaelNakayama replied to you in my post above..

Answer (score 0):

change the line:

`<button ng-click="login();">Login</button>`

in your HTML to

`<button type="submit">Login</button>`

So that the submit button submits the form as defined already on the line

```
<form name="login" ng-submit="login()">
```

Comment: When I do that, I get this in the console:                                                Server listening on port 8000       
GET / 304 12.536 ms - -
GET /?userid=test&pswrd=test 304 5.946 ms - -

Comment: You also have the line     `ng-app="loginPage" ng-controller="loginController"`    as part of the div that is inside the <form> tag. This code should be inside the <form> tag, as the form is referring to the     `login()`    function that resides in the loginController, and the    `ng-app`   should encompass the entire angular app.,